# How to make the history logs store in the spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've created a simple counter which has a single textbox, disabled box and a history to record all previous value in the disabled box.

It works perfectly, but somehow when the page is accidentally refreshed all the logs are deleted.

Is there a way to keep that record even if the page reload? Or maybe store it in a spreadsheet?

**CODE :**

```
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
let historyContainer = document.getElementById("history");
let history = [];

//listen key enter press on the input
box1.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value !== "") {
  const summedValue = (box2.value && box2.value.trim() === "")  ? Number(box2.value) : Number(box2.value) + Number(e.target.value)
  box2.value = summedValue;
  historyContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${box2.value}</p>`;
  box1.value = "";
  }
});
//reset the second box and
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box2.value = "";
  historyContainer.innerHTML = ""
});
<input type="number" id="box1" />
<input type="number" id="box2" disabled />
<div id="history">
</div>

<button type="button" id="reset">
Reset
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re talking about storing it in the browser, without any server code, you should consider [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) from the web storage API.

To save a value:

```js
localStorage.setItem(‘box2’, ‘value of box 2’);
```

To get it back:

```js
const value = localStorage.getItem(‘box2’);
```

---

Here's a modified version of your code that saves the history to local storage and pre-populates it when it initially runs.

> **NOTE: The local storage code in this snippet doesn't work on Stack Overflow due to security restrictions, but hopefully you can still see
>   how it works.**

```js
(() => {
  let box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
  let box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
  let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
  let historyContainer = document.getElementById("history");
  let history = [];
  
  try {
    // pre-populate the history from local storage.
    // NOTE: this WILL NOT WORK on stack overflow due to security restrictions.
    const historyContent = localStorage.getItem('historyContent');
    historyContainer.innerHTML = historyContent;
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log("can't load. can't access local storage:", e.message);
  }
  
  //listen key enter press on the input
  box1.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value !== "") {
      const summedValue = Number(box2.value.trim() || 0) + Number(e.target.value);
      box2.value = summedValue;
      historyContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${box2.value}</p>`;
      box1.value = "";
      
      try {
        // save new markup to local storage:
        // NOTE: this WILL NOT WORK on stack overflow due to security restrictions
        localStorage.setItem('historyContent', historyContainer.innerHTML);
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log("can't save. can't access local storage:", e.message);
      }
    }
  });

  //reset the second box and
  resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    box2.value = "";
    historyContainer.innerHTML = "";
    
    // clear historyContent from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('historyContent');
    
    // or clear all local storage
    localStorage.clear();
  });
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" id="box1" />
  <input type="number" id="box2" disabled />
  <div id="history"></div>
  <button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've already read about that article. But I don't know where to put it on my codes or how to do it. Can you provide me a sample code?

Comment: Also, having a button that can clear the stored data in the web browser. Is that possible?

Comment: Should I put your code at the top of my Javascript codes? Or inside of it?

Comment: Hang on. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do exactly, but I'll update my answer with some sample code.

Comment: Hi guys, both of your codes is not working. All the buttons in my html is not working when I tried puting the codes you provided and don't even know why it's not working.

Comment: I can't fix "not working" without additional information. Not working how? Are there errors in the console? Have you tried setting breakpoints and stepping through it to see where the problem lies?

Comment: What I mean is, I've replaced my code with your codes and what happen is, all the buttons on my counter is not working. Even if I clicked it a couple of times still no result. I didn't have any error message when I try to save the code after I replace it with your codes. I don't know what's the problem. Both of your codes is not working, have you tried the codes you've provided?

Comment: I've tried replacing my code with some of your codes and hoping that It would run. But apparently it's not and I don't what should be the problem since there's no error message

Comment: The code snippet above works for me. _I can't help you further without additional information about what the problem is._ I can't see your code and I can't see the behavior you're experiencing, so what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) to achieve your ideas, here I use localStorage as an example

Stores array data named history, and updates the storage location every time it is added

```
//listen key enter press on the input
box1.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value !== "") {
    const summedValue = (box2.value && box2.value.trim() === "") ? Number(box2.value) : Number(box2.value) + Number(e.target.value)
    box2.value = summedValue;

    history.push(summedValue);

    // Store data
    localStorage.setItem("history", history);

    historyContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${box2.value}</p>`;
    box1.value = "";
  }
});
```

Remove the storage array data when pressing the reset button

```
//reset the second box and
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box2.value = "";
  historyContainer.innerHTML = "";
  // Remove data
  localStorage.removeItem('history');
});
```

When the page is refreshed, read the storage location. If it is not undefined and the length is greater than 0, then take out the data and put it on the screen

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Get data
  const local_history = localStorage.getItem("history");
  if (typeof local_history !== "undefined" && local_history.length > 0) {
    let html_str = "";
    local_history.forEach(element => {
      html_str += `<p>${element}</p>`;
    });
    historyContainer.innerHTML = html_str;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code works I forgot to change the id of my input and disabled box. But it's working now! Awesome! Thank you much!

Comment: I'm happy to help ! Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi, Just want to ask if there's a way that all the numbers in the local Storage will sum up and will be displayed in the disabled box? Every time a value is stored it will sum up to the disabled box

Comment: Use getItem to get the value. Take my example as an example. The type of the data taken is an array. If it is a numeric array, you can do this: [1, 2, 3] .reduce ((a, b) => a + b ), The string array can do this ["1", "2", "3"]. Map (i => Number (i)). Reduce ((a, b) => a + b)

Comment: I've tried something using your code but what happened is every time a value is entered the stored data in the LocalStorage sum up and not in the disabled box. Can you provide a sample code so I can have a reference to do it? Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, do you mean that when the user enters a value, put the result of the stored data operation into the historyContainer?

Comment: The current situation is this: When a user entered a data it will be stored in the History Container and all previous data entered will be displayed in the disabled box. So for example I enter 45 it will be displayed in the disabled box and will be stored in the History Container.  What I want to do is, when I enter another number it will be stored in the History Container but in the disabled box it will just sum up. If I enter 5, my history container will now have 45 and 5 but my disabled box will have a value of 50 since 5 will be add up to the 45.

Comment: oh If you just want to display the sum on the screen, then as long as you take out the data, you can convert the strings into numbers and add them together. You can use parseInt (str) to convert